# .NET Unobtrusive validation custom date range attribute showing wrong date unless app pool is recycled

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, unobtrusive-validation

We have a .NET MVC application. In it we have the Unobtrusive Validation plugin and a custom validator for Date Ranges.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class DateRangeAttribute
Inherits ValidationAttribute
Implements IClientValidatable, IMetadataAware

'[redacted for brevity]

Public Sub New(minDate As String, maxDate As String, minDateRelativeDays As Integer, maxDateRelativeDays As Integer)
    MyBase.New(DefaultErrorMessage)

    If minDate = String.Empty Then
        Me.MinDate = Today
    Else
        Me.MinDate = ParseDate(minDate)
    End If

    If maxDate = String.Empty Then
        Me.MaxDate = Today
    Else
        Me.MaxDate = ParseDate(maxDate)
    End If

    Me.MinDate = Me.MinDate.AddDays(minDateRelativeDays)
    Me.MaxDate = Me.MaxDate.AddDays(maxDateRelativeDays)

End Sub

'[redacted for brevity]
```

The validation is used by adding the appropriate decoration to the property in the model

```
<Display(name:="Completed date"), DateRange("2000/01/01", Nothing, 0, 0), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True)>
```

In this instance, since 'Nothing' is passed to the `maxDate` parameter, it will be set to `Today`. This works fine, it will not allow you to put in a date that is later than Today, except it doesn't seem to "refresh" at the end of the day unless the IIS App Pool is recycled. When the App Pool is kept running from one day to the next, the date range validation fails because it thinks `Today` is still yesterday. This happens on the client side and server side. We don't use Output Caching or do anything to explicitly cache the result of the validator.

It acts like it caches what `Today` is, but this seems completely wrong. We've put a workaround in to force the App Pool to recycle at midnight, which has mitigated the problem, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Is a New DateRangeAttribute made every time it is needed, or is it created once and re-used?

Comment: @AndrewMorton a new instance of the model is created every time someone lands on the page, and the model has the appropriate decoration on the date property as shown above, so I assume a new one is created each time

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how helpful this will be as I'm not that familiar with VB.NET, but I had a very similar issue in an ASP.NET Core application I worked on and I think the theory behind my solution may be the same.

I found that the attributes seem to get created when the application is compiled, so any properties are set at that time and never change unless another method changes them. In my case I had a validation attribute that set MinDate and MaxDate parameters in the constructor, and so I saw the same problem as you are describing - the min/max dates were correct at first, but never changed, so were incorrect after a day.

I solved this problem by replacing the MinDate/MaxDate parameters with BeforeSteps and AfterSteps parameters, and having a couple of public methods that calculated and returned the minimum and maximum dates using these parameters.

---

## Previously not working code:

Attribute:

```
public class DateRangeFromTodayAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly DatePart _rangeType;
    public DateTime MinDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MaxValue;
    public bool IsDateOnly { get; set; }

    public DateRangeFromTodayAttribute(DatePart rangeType, int steps, StepType stepType, bool isDateOnly = true)
    {
        _rangeType = rangeType;
        IsDateOnly = isDateOnly;

        if (stepType == StepType.BeforeToday)
        {
            MinDate = GetCalculatedDate(-steps);
        }

        if (stepType == StepType.AfterToday)
        {
            MaxDate = GetCalculatedDate(steps);
        }
    }

    public DateRangeFromTodayAttribute(DatePart rangeType, int beforeToday, int afterToday, bool isDateOnly = true)
    {
        _rangeType = rangeType;
        IsDateOnly = isDateOnly;
        MinDate = GetCalculatedDate(-beforeToday);
        MaxDate = GetCalculatedDate(afterToday);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null && !(value is DateTime))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DateRangeFromTodayAttribute)} can only be used on DateTime properties.");
        }

        if (!(value is DateTime date))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        var minIsValid = date >= MinDate;
        var maxIsValid = date <= MaxDate;

        return minIsValid && maxIsValid
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }

    private DateTime GetCalculatedDate(int steps)
    {
        DateTime now = IsDateOnly ? DateTime.Today : DateTime.Now;
        return _rangeType switch
        {
            DatePart.Ticks => now.AddTicks(steps),
            DatePart.Milliseconds => now.AddMilliseconds(steps),
            DatePart.Seconds => now.AddSeconds(steps),
            DatePart.Minutes => now.AddMinutes(steps),
            DatePart.Hours => now.AddHours(steps),
            DatePart.Days => now.AddDays(steps),
            DatePart.Months => now.AddMonths(steps),
            DatePart.Years => now.AddYears(steps),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
    }
}

public enum DatePart
{
    Ticks,
    Milliseconds,
    Seconds,
    Minutes,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Months,
    Years,
}

public enum StepType
{
    BeforeToday,
    AfterToday,
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DateRangeFromTodayAttributeAdapter : AttributeAdapterBase<DateRangeFromTodayAttribute>
{
    public DateRangeFromTodayAttributeAdapter(DateRangeFromTodayAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer) : base(attribute, stringLocalizer)
    {
    }

    public override void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-daterangefromtoday", GetErrorMessage(context));
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "min", Attribute.IsDateOnly ? Attribute.MinDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : Attribute.MinDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "max", Attribute.IsDateOnly ? Attribute.MaxDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : Attribute.MaxDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

    public override string GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext)
    {
        return Attribute.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

---

## Working code

This is my new attribute and adapter code - see how the dates are no longer in the constructor:

Attribute:

```
public class DateRangeFromTodayAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DatePart RangeType { get; set; }
    public int? StepsBefore { get; set; }
    public int? StepsAfter { get; set; }
    public bool IsDateOnly { get; set; }

    public DateRangeFromTodayAttribute(DatePart rangeType, int steps, StepType stepType, bool isDateOnly = true)
    {
        RangeType = rangeType;
        IsDateOnly = isDateOnly;

        if (stepType == StepType.BeforeToday)
        {
            StepsBefore = steps;
        }

        if (stepType == StepType.AfterToday)
        {
            StepsAfter = steps;
        }
    }

    public DateRangeFromTodayAttribute(DatePart rangeType, int beforeToday, int afterToday, bool isDateOnly = true)
    {
        RangeType = rangeType;
        IsDateOnly = isDateOnly;
        StepsBefore = beforeToday;
        StepsAfter = afterToday;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null && !(value is DateTime))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DateRangeFromTodayAttribute)} can only be used on DateTime properties.");
        }

        if (!(value is DateTime date))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        DateTime minDate = GetMinDate();
        bool minIsValid = date >= minDate;

        DateTime maxDate = GetMaxDate();
        bool maxIsValid = date <= maxDate;

        return minIsValid && maxIsValid
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }

    public DateTime GetMinDate()
    {
        return StepsBefore is null
            ? DateTime.MinValue
            : GetCalculatedDate(-StepsBefore.Value);
    }

    public DateTime GetMaxDate()
    {
        return StepsAfter is null
            ? DateTime.MaxValue
            : GetCalculatedDate(StepsAfter.Value);
    }

    private DateTime GetCalculatedDate(int steps)
    {
        DateTime now = IsDateOnly ? DateTime.Today : DateTime.Now;
        return RangeType switch
        {
            DatePart.Ticks => now.AddTicks(steps),
            DatePart.Milliseconds => now.AddMilliseconds(steps),
            DatePart.Seconds => now.AddSeconds(steps),
            DatePart.Minutes => now.AddMinutes(steps),
            DatePart.Hours => now.AddHours(steps),
            DatePart.Days => now.AddDays(steps),
            DatePart.Months => now.AddMonths(steps),
            DatePart.Years => now.AddYears(steps),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
    }
}

public enum DatePart
{
    Ticks,
    Milliseconds,
    Seconds,
    Minutes,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Months,
    Years,
}

public enum StepType
{
    BeforeToday,
    AfterToday,
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DateRangeFromTodayAttributeAdapter : AttributeAdapterBase<DateRangeFromTodayAttribute>
{
    public DateRangeFromTodayAttributeAdapter(DateRangeFromTodayAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer) : base(attribute, stringLocalizer)
    {
    }

    public override void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-daterangefromtoday", GetErrorMessage(context));

        DateTime minDate = Attribute.GetMinDate();
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "min", Attribute.IsDateOnly ? minDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : minDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));

        DateTime maxDate = Attribute.GetMaxDate();
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "max", Attribute.IsDateOnly ? maxDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : maxDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    }

    public override string GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext)
    {
        return Attribute.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```